# How to logout from fabric in android studio from Mac?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using `Fabric` plugin in `Android Studio`, but a want to sign in from another account. so how can i logout from first account?

Comment: That answer is for Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Fabric` in `Android Studio` & just press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Mac).

Comment: Oddly, it is Control+L on mac as well